# Give an example of a non-abelian group G containing a proper normal subgroup N such that $G/N$ is abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups

Give an example of a non-abelian group G containing a proper normal subgroup N such that $G/N$ is abelian.

***I KNOW THERE IS A QUESTION OF THE SAME NAME.***

However, I need more involved assistance.

My professor suggested looking at the dihedral group $D_6$. I intend to find a homomorphism with a kernel that is the subgroup. The kernel of this homomorphism is a subgroup of G and is obviously normal.

However, why does this imply that $G/N$ is abelian, esp. since G itself is non-abelian?

Answer (score 4):

**HintL:** If the size of $G/N$ is very small, that will force Abelian.  One can also find an example using as $G$ a suitable symmetric group.

Comment: Could you explain a little more? My professor said that same thing, but am lost as to why.

Comment: For example, if the group $B/N$ has only two elements, it is automatically Abelian. So if you can find a non-Abelian group $G$ and a normal subgroup $N$ such that $G/N$ has order $2$, you will have an exaple.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $N$ be nonabelian, let $A$ be abelian non-trivial. Consider $N\times A$ and the projection $\pi\colon N\times A\to A$.