# The converse: If $G$ is abelian and if $N\le G$, prove that $G/N$ is abelian

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

Here is a problem from Herstein's "Topics in Algebra":

> If $G$ is abelian and if $N$ is any subgroup of $G$, prove that $G/N$ is abelian

I have already proved this; it's quite simple. There's a very natural question that arises: is the converse true?

I say it's not. The reason is because the quotient group $G/N$ always require $N$ to be normal in $G$, and although every subgroup of an abelian group is normal the converse is not true. So $G$ is not abelian.

Is my intuition faulty?

Comment: And also $N=C_n$ is a normal subgroup of $G=D_n$ with abelian quotient $G/N\cong C_2$, see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/717030/give-an-example-of-a-non-abelian-group-g-containing-a-proper-normal-subgroup-n-s).

Comment: Your intuition is not faulty, however it does not constitute a proof. For that, you need a counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $S_3$- it's a group of order 6, hence by Lagrange, any subgroup is of prime order, hence cyclic and abelian. However' $S_3$ isn't abelian

Comment: got it. thanks mate

Comment: Your'e welcome my friend :)